# databinding to changing element property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm working on a small WPF application in which I have a combobox that is bound to an ObservableCollection in the code behind:

```
public Molecule CurrentMolecule { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<string> Formulas { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
     CurrentMolecule = new Molecule();
     Formulas = new ObservableCollection<string>(CurrentMolecule.FormulasList.ToList());
     DataContext = this;

     InitializeComponent();
}

<ComboBox x:Name="cmbFormula" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Formulas}" SelectionChanged="cmbFormula_SelectionChanged"/>
```

This works fine to populate my combo box with the `CurrentMolecule.FormulasList` however if at some point I set `CurrentMolecule` to a new instance of Molecule the databinding no longer works. Do I need to implement some kind of OnPropertyChanged event so that no matter what the contents of the combo box will stay current with the `CurrentMolecule.FormulasList`?

Comment: Where do you populate your FormulaList?  Because from the looks of the code, your FormulaList for your new CurrentMolecule would be null.  That may just bet because we can't see where you are populating the FormulaList

Comment: FormulasList is a property of the Molecule object that returns a string[]. I have to do it this way in order to implement the IMolecule interface. I don't really think that Molecule or IMolecule are relevant to this particular question.

Comment: Is that string[] ever initialized?  It may be empty.

Comment: Its not empty... I already said that the combox box is populated just fine until I start moving around instances of Molecule objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, only then the changes will be updated in UI.

Here are the modifications that I've done to your code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Molecule _CurrentMolecule;

        public Molecule CurrentMolecule
        {
            get
            {
                return _CurrentMolecule;
            }
            set
            {
                _CurrentMolecule = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentMolecule");
                Formulas =  new ObservableCollection<string>(CurrentMolecule.FormulasList.ToList());
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<string> _Formulas;

        public ObservableCollection<string> Formulas
        {
            get { return _Formulas; }
            set
            {
                _Formulas = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Formulas");
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CurrentMolecule = new Molecule();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
A better approach is to create a ViewModel and then bind it to the DataContext of the `Window`.

Define a new class called `ViewModel` as below. Note you might want to change the namespace

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Properties
        private Molecule _CurrentMolecule;
        public Molecule CurrentMolecule
        {
            get
            {
                return _CurrentMolecule;
            }
            set
            {
                _CurrentMolecule = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentMolecule");
                Formulas = new ObservableCollection<string>(CurrentMolecule.FormulasList.ToList());
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<string> _Formulas;
        public ObservableCollection<string> Formulas
        {
            get { return _Formulas; }
            set
            {
                _Formulas = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Formulas");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public ViewModel()
        {
            CurrentMolecule = new Molecule();
        }
        #endregion

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Modify the `MainWindow` code behind file as below

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

Comment: While this solution may actually work, I strongly discourage the use of `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `DependencyObject`-derived classes. `INotifyPropertyChanged` is a ViewModel-concept, IMO, and should not be mashed all together with the View itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing WPF controls datacontext fundamentals. If you are using binding like {Binding CurrentMolecule.FormulasList} or parent controls datacontext is bound to "CurrentMolecule" whenever you swap DataContext of that item, the binding will reset. If you would like to keep the datacontext bound to the FormulasList even when the parent datacontext changes. You need to bind that context directly to FormulasList property and make sure that other parent controls are not using CurrentMolecule as a datacontext, even when its instance changes in your ViewModel.